# How to disable Emacs gnuclient warning on kill-buffer

Tags: emacs, gnuclient

When I run `M-x kill-buffer` for a buffer which was openend via `gnuclient`, I first get this prompt...

```
Kill buffer (default 'my-buffer-name'):
```

Then I get a second prompt/message...

```
Buffer 'my-buffer-name' belongs to gnuserv client(s); kill anyway? (yes or no)
```

How can I disable the second *gnuserv/client* message? (I don't need it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works for both with *gnuclient* or *emacsclient*, though its (original) docstring says, *"Kill buffer, taking gnuclient into account."* ... from *[emacswiki: KillKey](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-se/KillKey)*

```
(defun my-kill ()
  "Kill buffer, taking gnuclient into account."
  (interactive)
  (if (buffer-modified-p)
      (error "Buffer has unsaved changes")
    (if server-buffer-clients
 (server-edit)
      (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))
```

---

The above addresses the question, as asked, but aside from that, I have worked around the issue by using emacs' built-in *server* and *emacsclient* (vs. gnuclient, as mentioned in the question).

With this new server/client combination, I can *open* files in emacs, from a bash shell, as if they were opened (visited) from within emacs itself.

In a launcher script, eg. named `e`, this basic command does the trick; no more annoying prompts when I kill the buffer...

It also has the *added advantage* of allowing features like *[restoring VisibleBookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/VisibleBookmarks)*, etc to function for that file/buffer.

```
emacsclient -e "(find-file \"$1\")" &>/dev/null
```

I think that something similar could be done with GNU server/client, but I quite like *emacsclient*, so I'll run with it.